# Layout weight different behavior in Android 4 and Android 5

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I do have an Android application and it's been working perfectly fine in Androids 2.3 - 4.4 
Recently I wanted to update the application but I've noticed that in Android 5 my layouts are not laying out properly (or in other words are not laying out the same as they were in the previous versions).

I don't do Android Development on a daily basis so I am not up to date with all the changes, but did Android 5 change anything with the way Layout Weight work?

**UPDATE #1:**

I didn't really write what is the problem. In A5 LinearLayout below ListView isn't displayed. ListView takes whole screen height.

**UPDATE #2:**

Android 4

[image: Android 4]

Android 5

[image: Android 5]

For the records, my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/places_holder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_prev"
            android:src="@drawable/prev"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_party"
            android:src="@drawable/party"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_map "
            android:src="@drawable/map"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:src="@drawable/pin" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+1"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:background="@drawable/badgeshape"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/iv_next"
            android:src="@drawable/next" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, can you post screenshots for A4 and A5 to see the difference?

Comment: Will do in a moment. but I've realized that I didn't specify what's the problem. I will update question with the problem and later update it with screens.

Comment: please add your screenshots

Comment: Your layout works perfect in both versions. but the above images looks of different screen sizes, pls check whether are you obtaining the correct layout from the correct directory and the bottom layout is present in each layout or not.

Comment: If I change listview weight to 2 and set weight of places_holder to 1 then it's displayed just not properly. Img: http://imgur.com/szch1I3